# getting multiple errors for this code within the for loop and for the variable value;

Tags: c++

used the variable value as a size of an array but it will not let me.

```
int main () {
    double a,b,N,increment,value;
    value=0;
    cout<< "enter values for (a,b,N)";
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cin>>N;
    increment= (b-a)/(N-1);
    for (int i =0;i<=b;i+=increment){
    value = value+i;    
    }
    double sivalues[value];
    for (int x=a;i<=b;i+=increment){
        sivalues[a]=si(x);
        cout<<"si("<<x<<") = "<< sivalues[a];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The item placed inside the [] when creating an array must be **constant**.  This does not apply however when you create arrays on the heap.

```
int mySize = 50;
int myArray[mySize]; // error: mySize must be const
int* myHeapArray = new int[mySize]; // all good! (just don't forget to free the memory)
```